# How to limit to max. 1x Score Submission in Google Play Game Services leaderboard API?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard

My app is using the Google Play Game Services Leaderboard API.
So far everything seems fine.

I'm now stuck trying to figure out how to set a maximum limit of Score submission for each player. 
I'm not talking about DISPLAYING users only one best score on the leaderboard!!!

This one specific Leaderboard is based on players first time playing score!
I want to let everyone have only max. ONE shot to score the best score they possible can. Once their score has been submitted, there should be absolutely no way to submit a better score!!!

How do i do that? I know i could do this the crappy way, using a boolean value via sharedPrefs but that only works if the player does NOT reinstalls app or clears app data.

I have no clue how to do this. I hope there is some magic trick in the Google Play Games Service that i can use otherwise i will need to do this online - uploading and downloading variables from servers. I really hope i don't have to go this way, anyone with a better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is to do both :)
Once you have submitted a score, use the local sharedPrefs which can be checked much faster than pinging the server using something like [loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboards#loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int))

```
if (lastSubmittedScore() == null) { // read from local prefs, null if not set.
    // call Server
    PendingResult<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult> result =
        Games.Leaderboards.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(mGoogleApiClient, leaderboardId,
        TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, COLLECTION_PUBLIC);

    if (result.await().getScore() == null) {
        // no score - submit it
        Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient,leaderboardId, firstScore);
        // write out locally, that we scored
        saveLastSubmittedScore(firstScore);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the player is reinstalling the app or cleaning the local save files on his phone? That's a lil risky, sry :(

Comment: In the case of reinstalling, or something, the score won't be there, so it will check the server.  If you are super worried about it, you could skip the local caching step and always check the leaderboard on the service.